# Sort Named Range in random part of Worksheet - we couldn't find a range reference or a defined name

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, range

I've never tried to sort data that is not at the top of the worksheet but I have some oddly formatted data and I'm having trouble getting "sort" to work correctly. I continue to get error `we couldn't find a range reference or a defined name`.

The data looks like the image below and I'm trying to sort the data starting at row 18 by header "Method" then "Number". The data in this image is actually already sorted the way I'd want it. I have tested using `SELECT` and my named range can select the data properly, but my sort statement fails with aforementioned error. Any Suggestions?

Code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim fRowoffilterqcdata As Integer, lRowoffilterqcdata As Integer, lColoffilterqcdata As Integer
fRowoffilterqcdata = Cells(1, 8).End(xlDown).Row
lRowoffilterqcdata = Get_lRow(ActiveSheet)
lColoffilterqcdata = Cells(fRowoffilterqcdata, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim FilteredQCDataRng As Range
Set FilteredQCDataRng = Range(Cells(fRowoffilterqcdata, 1), Cells(lRowoffilterqcdata, lColoffilterqcdata))
FilteredQCDataRng.Select ' This Works
FilteredQCDataRng.Sort key1:="Method", key2:="Number", Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes ' This Failed

'Call FilterWorksheetHeaderRow(ActiveSheet, fRowoffilterqcdata)

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: The sort keys should be cells, not text.

Comment: I've never had issues using "text" before, are you sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `Columns("A:T")` format I am able to use "Column Headers" as text but when using a named range, I had to use "Range" as well for the keys.

Eg:

This Works:

```
Columns("A:T").Sort key1:="Method", key2:="Number", Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

But this doesn't:

```
FilteredQCDataRng.Sort key1:="Method", key2:="Number", Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

This is Works:

```
FilteredQCDataRng.Sort key1:=Range("B32"), key2:=Range("F32"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```